# TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default().models is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I doing a model in next.js app using mongoose, when i trying to call the model in the homepage components i get this issue (TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default().models is undefined)

my model code:-

```
`
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import { Schema, models, model } from "mongoose"
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },




    size: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },



    amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },


    
    images: [
        {
            public_id: {
                type: String

            },

            url: {
                type: String
            }
        }
    ],

    
});



export default mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
`
```

My Homepage code :-

```
<div className='card'>

<img className='w-full h-full object-cover' width='100' height='100' src="../../assets/media/image1.png"/>

<div className="p-5 flex flex-col gap-4">
  
  <h2 className='product-title font-semibold text-2x1 overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden whitespace-nowrap '>{property.title}</h2>

    <span className='text-xl font-normal'>USD {product.amount}</span>


    </div>
  </div>

</div>


</div>

</div>
```

I tried to update mongoose edit codes import mongoose in all pages